# Can the log level of a (python) ROS node be changed dynamically?

Tags: ros, python, rospy, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder if it is possible (and if not if it makes sense) to change the log level of a python node during runtime.

The node could connect to a special purpose topic where the log level for the node can be announced. This would allow to have a node running without the debug messages being published to /rosout, but if necessary the log level could be switched to debug if the node is not running as expected.

Of course you can always change the init_node line and re-run the node, but in some occasions a more transparent solution might be useful?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44922/can-the-log-level-of-a-(python)-ros-node-be-changed-dynamically?/) by [Felix Kaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2655/felix-kaser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although not currently/officially supported by the `rospy` api, this can be accomplished through a simple function.  See the accepted answer for [Change python node log level while running](http://answers.ros.org/question/9802/change-python-node-log-level-while-running/).

---

Originally posted by [JeremyRoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90800/jeremyroy/) with karma: 51 on 2021-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-12-06**:
Since this old thread is about ROS1, which is basically frozen for new feature addition, non-complex workaround is probably an acceptable answer and solution. So I marked this as a selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That would be quite useful, but is not currently supported.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe a duplicate of [Change python node log level while running](http://answers.ros.org/question/9802/change-python-node-log-level-while-running/)

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3